# Why does my getImageId function only fire off the first time my code runs?

Tags: reactjs, axios

Originally had issues with an image loop (it was killing our api calls) and realized we needed to remove componentDidUpdate.  Now when inspecting the page with React Dev Tools I can see everything except for the img src updates including the alt tag.  If nothing has been rendered to the page then it will render the information correctly but once something is there it changes everything except for the image its self.

```
class Img extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        src: ""
    }
}

// componentDidUpdate() {
//     this.getImageId();
// }
componentDidMount() {
    this.getImageId();
}

getImageId() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/images/${this.props.src}`)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data) //this shows only on first request
            this.setState({
                src: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
render() {
    return ( <img src = {
            this.state.src
        }
        alt = {
            this.props.alt
        }
        style = {
            {
                height: "150px",
                width: "200px",
                borderRadius: "10px"
            }
        }
        />
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Well in theory, why would you ever need to get the image more than one time?

Comment: The amount of images isnt the issue its that once a game or a list of games is rendered the first time everything except for the game cover image changes.

Comment: solution still working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, your component will only make an API request a single time. And that logic is executed in `componentDidMount()`. It is a `lifecycle` event that is executed right after the component is rendered the first time, and never again.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getImageId();
}
```

The `componentDidUpdate()` logic you commented out is creating an endless loop. First your initial `getImageId()` call runs in `componentDidMount()`. It makes an API request, then it responds with some data and you update component-state with that data.

Any time state or props are updated you trigger `componentDidUpdate()`. And as currently constructed, your `componentDidUpdate()` calls `getImageId()`, which updates state, which then triggers `componentDidUpdate()`, which then calls `getImageId()`, which... you get the picture.

You can workaround this. If you only want to make recurring calls to your API when a new `src` is passed down as a prop from your parent. Do this instead:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(this.props.src !== prevProps.src){
      this.getImageId()
   }
}
```

So now, you only make a new request when there is an updated `src` provided.

Comment: That works as long as I just want to render 1 game at a time and it breaks if you refresh the page now. I was planning on rendering 5 to 10 at a time.

Comment: @TylerEdge nice, hope its still working as I type this message lool.